# Removing rows and comparing months

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables for client debts. The first one is:

> client_debts: (***id***, client_name, total_debts, date_now, time_now)

And client_details table where it is connected to client_debts with a foreign key, and inside of it, we add the payment of each client

> client_details: (***id***, **client_id**, payment, date_now, time_now)

What I want to do is, to make an `INNER JOIN` where I select client_name, and his total_debs, with a column from client_details, that makes the sum of payment for each `client_id`. So iI tried this:

```
SELECT t1.client_name, t1.total_debts, t2.client_id, sum(payment) as 'payments' 
FROM client_debts t1
INNER JOIN client_details t2
ON t1.id = t2.client_id
GROUP BY t2.client_id
```

And the result was like this:

[image]

The black colored row, is where a client pay all of his debts on a product, even if he have other debts because he bought other products, so I need to remove this row from the table. So I tried to add an `AND` to this `JOIN` query.

```
SELECT t1.client_name, t1.total_debts, t2.client_id, sum(payment) as 'payments' 
FROM client_debts t1
INNER JOIN client_details t2
ON t1.id = t2.client_id AND t1.total_debts<>'payment'
GROUP BY t2.client_id
```

But the result is still the same:

[image]

**Now what I really want to do, is to remove rows where clients pays total debts is equal to their payments, and add a new condition, where I take from client_details the date, and extract the month and compare it to current month, to see if a client pays this month or still didn't.**

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: if i understand your question correctly it should be `t1.total_debts<>sum(payment)`

Comment: I tried it and it gives me the followinf error: `Invalid use of group function`, but it works when I used it as `payment`

Comment: yeah but what your query is doing is total_debts is not equal to String payment

Comment: sir, I want to display only clients that they didn't pay all their debts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT  main.* 
FROM    (SELECT    t1.client_name, t1.total_debts, t2.client_id, sum(payment) payments , t2.date_now ,
                    CASE MONTH(t2.date_now)  
                       WHEN MONTH(CURDATE()) THEN 'Paid'
                       ELSE 'Not Paid'
                    END current_month
        FROM client_debts t1  INNER JOIN client_details t2  ON t1.id = t2.client_id 
        GROUP BY t2.client_id) main
WHERE   main.total_debts<> main.payments;
```

Comment: error `every derived table should have its own alias`

Comment: @androidnation fixed query for mysql, give it a try

Comment: Sir, I need you to help me with something else, sometimes a client buy 2 items, but it only this month pays for one items, so practically he pays, and then I don't want to display his name in the list of `Not Paid Yet`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34761796/changing-a-complex-inner-join-query-and-displaying-it-with-php/